# How to open a file in a new process everytime irrespective of fileopener

Tags: python-2.7, winapi, subprocess, popen

I am using windows 7 64 bit python 2.7 I am opening the file, and monitoring the file changes and then waiting till the opened file is closed. This works well in case of simple notepad file opener. As notepad opens each files in a new process ID whereas notepad++ opens different files in a single notepad++ process ID.

```
ACTIONS = {
  1 : "Created",
  2 : "Deleted",
  3 : "Updated",
  4 : "Renamed from something",
  5 : "Renamed to something"
}
FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, fileName, directory, origin):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.daemon = True
        self.dir = directory
        self.originalFile = origin
    def run(self):
        startMonitor(self.fileName, self.dir, self.originalFile)

def startMonitor(fileMonitoring,dirPath,originalFile):
    hDir = win32file.CreateFile (
      dirPath,
      FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
      win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
      None,
      win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
      win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
      None
    )
    readFlags = win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME  | \
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME   | \
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES | \
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE       | \
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | \
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY
    # Wait for new data and call ProcessNewData for each new chunk that's written
    while 1:
        # Wait for a change to occur
        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
                                                   hDir,
                                                   1024,
                                                   False,
                                                   readFlags,
                                                   None
                                                   )
        # For each change, check to see if it's updating the file we're interested in
        for action, file_M in results:
            full_filename = os.path.join (dirPath, file_M)
            #print file, ACTIONS.get (action, "Unknown")
            if len(full_filename) == len(fileMonitoring) and action == 3:
                #copy to main file
                if os.path.exists(originalFile):
                        encrypt_file(key,fileMonitoring,originalFile,iv)





thread1 = myThread(1, FileName, tempLocation,selectedFileName)
thread1.start();
startupinfo = None
if os.name == 'nt':
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    **ss=subprocess.Popen(FileName,shell=True)**
    ss.communicate()
    os.remove(FileName)
```

So above code, it works when I close notepad++(which will close all different opened files which is not desired) instead of closing only the opened file type. 
**When I open file with wordpad/notepad then each process of it is created with a file.
Whereas with notepad++, only a single process of notepad++ carries all the different file types**. So, how to **invoke new process ID for different types of file openers like notepad++, msoffice, openoffice each time it opens a new fil** In above case **ss.communicate()** is not a blocking call

Comment: Maybe notepad++ has some command line parameters that update the text area. As I remember it asks if it should update the text area when it gets the focus again.

Comment: What is the purpose of the whole script? Do you want to find out when an external application done with the file you give it? Does `notepad++` keeps the file open i.e., can you open it in another program while it is opened by `notepad++`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If notepad++ is your default application for opening any txt file, then it will open that in another tab, but there exist only a single process of notepad++ even though multiple files are opened. So, I want to start a separate process of notepad++ for each file. Similarly, if for .docx file ms word is default application, then it will initiate separate process of msword.  My aim is to open any file type with default application and listen to the changes made in the file.

Comment: @winterfall: *"My aim is to open any file type with default application"* -- `os.startfile()`. *"and listen to the changes made in the file. "* -- [`watchdog`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example) (your code also might work). Also, if the answer to the last question from [my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278825/how-to-open-a-file-in-a-new-process-everytime-irrespective-of-fileopener#comment33322654_21278825) is yes then you could just try `open()` in a loop until it succeeds (as poorman's `watchdog` substitute).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian please see the code, `ss.communicate()` is not waiting in notepad++.So, it execute next line of code and deletes the opened file. As said in question, a single notepad++ process opens many files. It can be solved if everytime a file opens in a new process. But how to invoke a new process of notepad++

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am using the native windows file monitor. If I close notepad++. And then OPEN file with nodepad++, `ss.communicate()` is blocking. But to come out of it, I have to close notepad++, not by mere closing the opened file

Comment: I don't see why do you care whether `ss.communicate()` blocks or not (just use `os.startfile()` -- it always returns as soons as the application is launched (it doesn't wait for the application to exit)). If you need to know when it is safe to delete the file then just try to delete it in a loop (with a sleep to avoid busy loop). Or if you know what changes you need to monitor for then delete it in the "file monitoring" part of your code.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian "and listen to the changes made in the file" how, since process is not waiting. It terminates as soon as file is opened and deletes the file. Thats why i used ss.communicate() to wait, till file is closed and then terminate the process.

Comment: `ss.communicate()` says you *nothing* in the general case: It may return *before* the file is closed; it may return long *after* the file is closed.