# Alternate of subprocess.call(["open","-W", FileName]) in python on osx

Tags: python, macos, applescript, subprocess

I am using mac osx and python 2.7 Through https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html I used `subprocess.call(["open","-W", FileName])`. But in this case, **Causes `open` to wait until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited.**  So, it is not desired. I want that `open` to wait, till particular opened file is closed irrespective whether application it opens have exited or not(so there may be previous opened files remains with that particular application)
I also asked in [Blocking call while opening a file in python on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076449/blocking-call-while-opening-a-file-in-python-on-osx/22076898?noredirect=1#comment33508341_22076898) but didn't get the desired answer

Comment: FYI, CamelCase is not considered conventional for variable names in Python. See PEP-8 for more: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: *"I want that `open` to wait, till particular opened file is closed irrespective whether application it opens have exited or not"* -- does `lsof` work on OSX?

Comment: related: [How to open a file in a new process everytime irrespective of fileopener](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21278825/4279). Similar problem, different OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
handle = subprocess.Popen(['open', '-W', filename])
```

...and go about your day; this will start the subprocess, but not block for its exit. You still have the `handle` if you want to check on the process's status. (Storing this handle may be necessary to prevent garbage collection).

If you need to handle the case where an already-open editor instance handles the file -- and to enforce blocking until only this file within that preexisting instance is closed -- this is not possible without editor-specific support.

Comment: Suppose file is abc.txt then subprocess.Popen(["open","-W", FileName]) will open it in TextEdit. Then subprocess.Popen(["open","-W", FileName]) is waiting till TextEdit is not force quit. Suppose I have a multi-tab text editor open and I run my application. text file will be opened in a tab on my already-running editor. Then my program will refuse to continue until I close all of my tabs, including the ones that had nothing to do with my task. This scenario i want to avoid

Comment: What does "waiting till TexEdit is not force quit" mean?

Comment: I want to block till that particular file is closed irrespective of other files of that application.  subprocess.Popen(['open', '-W', filename]) will wait till TexEdit is not force quit from dock location, i.e. killing of TexEdit  process

Comment: Ahh. Easy answer -- you can't. The application doesn't provide that kind of feedback.

Comment: Nothing robust. You could block until the file is next written to, but that mean that if someone saves their work-in-progress before they're done you'd be starting early, and if they closed the editor without making changes you wouldn't know it. Anyhow, that kind of hack is bad enough (re: surprising users by doing something they don't want/expect) that it's better not to try.

Comment: Well -- you can also look at whether a specific editor has appropriate functionality available, but that would make it a question about that editor in particular.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: In principle, you could get the spawned process tree and all open files using `psutil`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, that's only if the editor keeps the file open while it's being modified. Not all editors do; it's rather common to close the handle when done with the read, and reopen for write on save.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point. In that case, "you can't." is the correct answer unless a specific editor is targeted.